# Javascript promises not working the way they should when using Promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise

I am having problems with some code when I just can't find why the Promises are not working the way they should.

The function called "start" is the one that calls all the other functions so it's all started there.

Function is at the bottom and it's excecuted using:

```
start(filename);
```

Up to there it's all ok but the problem is that the functions should all finish executing before Promise.all is processed (which should be last).

This is not what's happening...What's happening is that Promise.all is executing before all the functions have finished their job.

I just can't find the problem.

Here is the code:

```
export default function createDataset(filename, callback) {

    const dataset = {};
    const promises = [];

    function setResults() {

        const checkPathExists = fs.access(possiblePath)
            .then(() => {
                dataset.results_fullpath = possiblePath;
            })
            .catch(() => {
                dataset.results_fullpath = '';
            });

        promises.push(checkPathExists);

        return checkPathExists;
    }

    function tree() {

        const checkCloudFileReadable = fs.access(cloudFilePath, fs.constants.R_OK)
            .then(() => {
                dataset.potreePointCloud = cloudFilePath;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                dataset.potreePointCloud = '';
            });

        promises.push(checkCloudFileReadable);
    }


    function setLink() {

        const checkPathExists = fs.access(LinkPath)
            .then(() => fs.readFileSync(LinkPath, {'encoding': 'utf8'}))
            .catch(err => {
                // log error if not an expected error
                // error here

            });

        promises.push(checkPathExists);
    }


    function loadErrorText() {
        if (dataset.state === 'error') {
            const errorFilePath = path.join(dataset.path_parts.dir, `${dataset.path_parts.base}-report.txt`);

            dataset.error_file_path = errorFilePath;

            const readErrorFile = fs.readFile(errorFilePath, 'utf8')
                .then(errorData => {
                    dataset.error_text = errorData;
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    dataset.error_text = 'Cannot find error report';
                });

            promises.push(readErrorFile);
        }
    }

    function loadWarningText() {
        if (dataset.state === 'complete') {
            const warningFilePath = path.join(dataset.results_fullpath, 'warnings.txt');

            const readWarningFile = fs.readFile(warningFilePath, 'utf8')
                .then(warningData => {
                    dataset.warning_text = warningData;
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    dataset.warning_text = '';
                });

            promises.push(readWarningFile);
        }
    }


    function loadResultFiles(parentFolderContents) {
        dataset.result_files = [];

        const resultFileExtensions = ['ply'];
        const resultsFiles = parentFolderContents.filter(fileName => {
            const splitFilename = fileName.split('.');

            return splitFilename.length >= 2 &&
                resultFileExtensions.indexOf(splitFilename[splitFilename.length - 1]) !== -1;
        });

        dataset.result_files = resultsFiles;

        if (resultsFiles.indexOf('summary.txt') !== -1) {
            fs.readJson(path.join(dataset.results_fullpath, 'summary.txt'), (err, summaryObject) => {
                if (!err) {
                    dataset.summary = summaryObject;

                    if (summaryObject !== undefined && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(summaryObject, 'date_modified')) {
                        dataset.modified = new Date(summaryObject.date_modified);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }


    function check(parentFolderContents) {

        if (files.length >= 1) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }


    function start(fullpath) {

        const statPath = fs.stat(fullpath)
            .then(stat => {
                if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(dataset, 'modified')) {
                    dataset.modified = stat.mtime;
                }

                dataset.bytesize = stat.size;
            })
            .catch(() => {
                if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(dataset, 'modified')) {
                    dataset.modified = new Date(Date.now());
                }
            });

        promises.push(statPath);

        if (dataset.path_parts.base.startsWith('complete-')) {
            dataset.state = 'complete';
            dataset.name = dataset.path_parts.name.slice('complete-'.length);
            setResults()
                .then(() => {
                    setLink();
                    tree();
                    loadWarningText();

                    const readPath = fs.readdir(dataset.results_fullpath);

                    promises.push(readPath);

                    return readPath;
                })
                .then(folderContents => {
                    loadResultFiles(folderContents);
                    check(folderContents);
                });

        } else {
            dataset.name = dataset.path_parts.name;
        }

        dataset.key = dataset.name;
    }

    start(filename);

    Promise.all(promises)
        .then(() => {
            if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback(dataset);
            }
        });

    return dataset;
}
```

How can I fix this to force Promise.all to wait till all the other functions have finished?

Comment: You're right, Javascript's promise/all functionality is broken \s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These three functions:

```
setLink();
tree();
loadWarningText();
```

will push a promise to `promises`, which  should then be awaited by `Promise.all`. However you call `Promise.all` on `promises` before you call these three, therefore you do not await them. To solve that, just discard that weird global mutated `promises` array, just return the promises from your functions, so instead of

```
promises.push(checkPathExists);
```

just do:

```
    return checkPathExists;
```

Then in your `start` function just chain them:

```
setResults()
  .then(() => Promise.all([
      setLink(),
      tree(),
      loadWarningText()
  ])).then(() => fs.readdir(dataset.results_fullpath))
  .then(/*...*/)
```

`dataset` should then be passed through that chain for the same reasons `promises` is bad.